# Online ticketing of National Express buses in UK

Tags: uk, buses

National express is the largest coach services operator in UK. The ticket can be purchased online or in their office.

1. Instead of £1 online booking fee, is there any difference between online purchasing and in store?
2. The e-ticket purchased online have to be printed, or via SMS/mobile with extra fee. If I did not choose SMS/mobile ticket but I lose my printed ticket and impossibly reprint before departure, what can i do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have been allowed on to a national express bus by showing them the eticket on my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still show the booking confirmation email with the details that you have received to the bus driver without printing and they will accept that.

In the store you can buy your ticket without paying the £1 fee however,  I doubt they have the cheapest fare that we book through online.  I am not so sure about this one.  That's as per my understanding and experience.